# Oracle Apex: redirect to the page user requested after login

Tags: oracle, session, redirect, authentication, oracle-apex-5

I am using Oracle APEX 5.0 on Oracle 12c. I have a situation where a user opens a link to an apex page from his email and he is redirected to the login page because there is no session exists.

e.g. the link that user clicks is:
http://host:port/apex/f?p=app_id:page:::::ITEM1,ITEM2:VAL1,VAL2

After clicking this link the user is moved to the login page. My question is after a successful login, how can we redirect him to the link he originally tried to access along with the parameters and values originally passed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there's a way; follow this path:

Edit application properties >> Security tab >> Session management >> **Deep linking** >> set it to "**Enabled**"

From the documentation:

> This attribute enables or prevents deep linking to an application.
>   Options include:
>
> - Enabled - The URL to a specific page ultimately redirects there, possibly after the user has to logged in.
> - Disabled - If the URL does not contain a valid session ID, Application Express redirects to the application's home page.
>
> For example, browsers often save the URLs of opened tabs and try to
>   restore the sessions after a restart, causing a deep link. This
>   behavior may be undesirable (for example if a URL points to a page in
>   the middle of a multi-step wizard). By selecting Disable, Application
>   Express starts a new session and redirects to the application's home
>   page.
>
> Note you can override this application setting at page-level.